# Pricing of google cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I want to understand the pricing of gcs. I have looked at the examples from gcs homepage, however i have trouble understanding egress, ingress, geo location differences etc.

Can someone help me with a breakdown of the price of the following workflow in google cloud storage. I live in Mexico.

1. Upload 1TB from my computer to a bucket
2. Store it for 1 month in us-east1 in standard storage
3. Download all 1TB to my computer

Comment: Maybe use the Google pricing calculator .... here is an example: https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/#id=30beb29c-bfc7-4cf4-adc5-1bc319a37064

Comment: Thanks, it makes it easier to calculate. The problem is that I don't know which stats I hit when downloading/uploading/storing. I would say network egress and storage. 
1) Are there others? 
2) Egress is what I upload or download to gcs?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 1):

I did the calculation and they are $ 40.96 based on this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/disks-image-pricing) where I used the example of the `Standard provisioned space` and I did the following operation: $ 0.040 x 1024 = $ 40.96 if you want to know how much you would pay for other components you can check it [here](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/)

Comment: The docs you provide are for compute engine, i am using google cloud storage. However, gcs has something similar. But my question regarding gcs... I don't need to pay for bandwidth (#1 and #3)?

Answer (score 0):

Upload is free, [storage is calculated by second](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#storage-pricing) (even is presented here per month, in the billing page it's presented in GB/s), download is free if you aren't in [nearline, coldline or archive class](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#archival-pricing), expect the [egress bandwidth for downloading the size](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#network-egress)

You need to substract the [5Gb/month free storage and 1Gb of egress](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#cloud-storage-always-free) (forget this for 1Tb, it's not really significant.)

Comment: Thanks for the links. Guess, you made a typo. As I understand, egress/download has a cost.

Comment: Please stop providing answers to questions that are clearly off-topic to Stack overflow (billing, pricing, legal, etc.). SO is **not** Google's first level helpdesk.